# Graph API - adding custom column with employeeid from prebuilt script

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I am using a Microsoft provided 365 active user report via Graph API, however it is missing only one thing that I need - and that is employeeNumber. We have recently extended our schema, and I can query on employeeNumber like so:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber`

The output from the code below gives me all licensed, active 365 users, as well as their license types, but I would like to somehow also include the employeeNumber column. I'm not sure this is even possible, considering this is a canned Microsoft report.

Would I just build a report object with the results of `$reports`, and then run a separate query to get all employeeNumbers, and somehow insert that column? I think I could match them by using `userPrincipalName`.

```
# CHANGE THESE VALUES
$TenantID = 'tenantid' #The Directory ID from Azure AD
$ClientID = 'ClientID ' #The Application ID of the registered app
$ClientSecret = 'ClientSecret ' #The secret key of the registered app
# ------------------------------------------------------

# DO NOT CHANGE THESE
$body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body
$token = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}
# ------------------------------------------------------
 
$graphApiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D90')"
$Reports = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $graphApiUri -Headers $token | ConvertFrom-Csv
$Reports | Export-Csv "c:\temp\GraphAPI365UsersReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Updated script, works great.

```
# Application (client) ID, Directory (tenant) ID, and secret
$clientID = "clientID"
$tenantID = "tenantID"
$ClientSecret = "ClientSecret"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"

#Get token
Write-Output "Acquire Graph Token."
try {
    $body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
    $oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body
    $token = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Error getting Graph Token."
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    EXIT
}
# ------------------------------------------------------
 
$graphApiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D90')"

$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$select=userPrincipalName,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber"

$O365Report = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $graphApiUri -Headers $token | ConvertFrom-Csv

# If the result is more than 999, we need to read the @odata.nextLink to show more than one side of users
$UserDetails = while (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($uri)) {
    # API Call
    $apiCall = try {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $token -Uri $uri -Method Get
    }
    catch {
        $errorMessage = $_.ErrorDetails.Message | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
    $uri = $null
    if ($apiCall) {
        # Check if any data is left
        $uri = $apiCall.'@odata.nextLink'
        $apiCall
    }
}

$O365Report | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentEmpNumber = $UserDetails.value |
        Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -Value $CurrentEmpNumber
}

$O365Report | Export-Csv "c:\temp\GraphAPI365UsersReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those reports are indeed pretty static unfortunately, getting the info you want shouldn't be hard though. I don't have your extension, but something like this should work:

```
$Reports = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $graphApiUri -Headers $token | ConvertFrom-Csv
$Uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber'
$UserDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -Headers $token
$Reports | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentEmpNumber = $UserDetails.value |
        Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name EmployeeNumber -Value $CurrentEmpNumber
}
$Reports | Export-Csv "c:\temp\GraphAPI365UsersReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

On a related note, why did you extend the schema for this? There's already an EmployeeId attribute in Azure AD, so `extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber` in the code above could just have been `employeeId`.

Comment: We have both employeeId and employeeNumber in our on premises AD.

I got this error:

`Select-Object : Property "extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber" cannot be found.`

So, I removed the spaces to change `$_.'User Principal Name'` to `$_.'UserPrincipalName'` , and it inserts the column into the output however the column contains no records.

Comment: The spaces need to be there, you're getting null results without them. The error suggests that the attribute name you gave is wrong, I would start by double checking that.

Comment: Yes sir - that is the correct attributename. I am actually seeing some values even though I get the error in the console - but only getting 11 values for extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber returned - there should be much more than that, considering we have over 7500 users in our tenant. I think this is because I need to loop to the next '@odata.nextLink

Comment: Aha, that could explain it! I've only tested on a small personal tenant. I probably won't get a chance to do more today, but that should be easy to fix.

Comment: Thank you! I can take it from here I suppose. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I just posted the updated code - but I'm still only getting 11 results.

Comment: You're rewriting `$UserDetails` every loop, try this instead `$UserDetails = while($uri){`

Comment: Hmm....doesn't seem to want to finish. Did I just create an infinite loop? Updated code above. I can confirm `userdetails.value | select userprincipalname,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber` does show all of the values.

Comment: Weird. I usually use a `do ... until` loop for this but a `while` should work fine, So your code in the comment above shows all UPNs with their employeeNumbers? In that case the loop isn't needed in any case. It's strange though, my output of /users has the property of `User Principal Name` with the spaces... But even if that is different, if you can see all the emplyeeNumbers in  $UserDetails the code *should* work.

Comment: Yes sir, it does if I set a breakpoint after the `@odata.nextlink` block, and confirm the values in `userdetails.value` however when it moves to your code to expand the property, I get an error: `Select-Object : Property "extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber" cannot be found.`

Comment: What does `$UserDetails.value | Get-Member -Name *Number | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` show? Does it match exactly what we're trying to select?

Comment: No, I only get results if I do `$userdetails.value | select extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber` and the `$uri = $UserDetails.'@odata.nextLink'` doesn't seem to want to finish either. I let it run for quite a while, and selecting all the users in our tenant doesn't take that long.

Comment: `$UserDetails.value | get-member -name *` only shows userPrincipalName, there's no mention of employeenumber unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how `$userdetails.value | select extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber` can work if there's only an UPN attribute. What about piping to just `Get-Member`? Should be the same, but something is strange here.

Comment: That's where I see `Equals,GetHashCode,GetType,ToString,userPrincipalName` but UPN is the only  `NoteProperty`

Comment: And you're saying if you run `$userdetails.value | select extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber` without doing any new queries or anything, right after, you actually see the emplyeeNumbers? It seems, well, impossible.

What does `$UserDetails.value.psobject.Properties.Name` show?

Comment: `Count
Length
LongLength
Rank
SyncRoot
IsReadOnly
IsFixedSize
IsSynchronized`

Comment: Got this to work! Next step would be to suppress the warnings where an employeeNumber cannot be found - some users in our tenant do not have employeeNumbers if they are service accounts, etc. Thanks again for your help @PMental